# Users uploads audio to play only on client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, client, html5-audio

Very simply, I just want a user to choose an audio file from their directory, and have the webpage just play the audio file that they uploaded.

I don't want to send the data to the server; I just want the audio file to reside on clientside.

There's a similar guide to do it for [images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications), but I'm not sure how to get started doing it for audio? What API's am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using Javascript. I've included comments in the code.

If you haven't already, just familiarize yourself with the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object and the [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method.

**Try uploading an audio file in the snippet below to see it in action.**

```js
//get input by id
var audioFile = document.getElementById("file")
//get source by id
var audioSource = document.getElementById("audioSource");
//get audio by id
var audioTag = document.getElementById('audio');

//apply event listener to input using the playAudio function
audioFile.addEventListener("change", function() {
  playAudio(this);
});


function playAudio(input) {
  //empty var to read file
  var reader;
  //if a file is uploaded then use FileReader to read file
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    //onload set the audio source with the uploaded audio
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      audioSource.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      //load source
      audioTag.load();
      //play source
      audioTag.play();
    }
    //read contents of of file
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<audio id="audio">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
</audio>
```